# Is it possible to make hover effect on images using graphics?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am trying to make hover effect on multiple images in Swing using graphics, I know this can be done by using CSS but confused to make this effect in Java, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is quite possible to do that.

Assume you have a `JPanel` with an image inside it that you want to change every time the user hovers over it. The code would be something like this:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // create a JPanel
this.setupGI(panel); // prepare your background
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());  // add a listener
this.getContentPane.add(panel); // add it to JApplet / JFrame
```

This is to add the listener where `MouseHandler` will be your custom handler class.

```
class MouseHandler extends java.awt.event.MouseAdapter{
  @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
    // your logic here
  }
  @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
    //
  }
}
```

Now, how the `MouseHandler` class will get access to the `JPanel`, well that is up to you. Usually, I make the handler class a sub-class so it has access to all the methods, fields of the enclosing class. Alternatively, you can make getter and setter methods. It is up to you.

More here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Answer (score 0):

Use MouseListener with events mouseEntered and mouseExited.

Comment: But actually Swing not fine selection to implenemt gimmick. If you want them, better look on JavaFX.